# CentOS 6 Gnome login immediately logs me out

Tags: centos, windows-server-2008-r2, samba, winbind, centos6

Have a strange issue on freshly installed CentOS 6, with Samba Windows 2008 R2 authentication.

The login succeeds, and even the home directory created, but then I'm thrown back to the login scren again. The message log contain the following errors:

```
Aug 22 11:35:01 linuxdevX gdm-simple-greeter[2295]: WARNING: Failed to send buffer
Aug 22 11:35:02 linuxdevX NetworkManager[1151]: <error> [1314002102.259224] [nm-manager.c:1312] user_proxy_init(): could not init user settings proxy: (3) Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerUserSettings': no such name
Aug 22 11:35:02 linuxdevX NetworkManager[1151]: <error> [1314002102.604082] [nm-manager.c:1312] user_proxy_init(): could not init user settings proxy: (3) Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerUserSettings': no such name
Aug 22 11:35:03 linuxdevX NetworkManager[1151]: <error> [1314002103.899317] [nm-manager.c:1312] user_proxy_init(): could not init user settings proxy: (3) Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerUserSettings': no such name
Aug 22 11:35:09 linuxdevX NetworkManager[1151]: <error> [1314002109.265723] [nm-manager.c:1312] user_proxy_init(): could not init user settings proxy: (3) Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManagerUserSettings': no such name
Aug 22 11:35:16 linuxdevX gdm-simple-greeter[2582]: Gtk-WARNING: gtkwidget.c:5460: widget not within a GtkWindow
```

Winbind logs do not show any errors.

Any idea what could be the culprit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it out with PowerBroker Identity Services Open Edition:
http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/

Worked out of box, without the complications of samba.